# Get stored procedure output value from SQL Server in ASP.NET with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that updates a record, before that check what name to enter does not have another record, in case it registers or will not return a message, which I can not catch in my controller.

My stored procedure is:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ACTUALIZAR_MARCA
    @IIDMARCA INT,
    @NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),
    @DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(200),
    @MENSAJE INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Marca WHERE NOMBRE = @NOMBRE AND IIDMARCA <> @IIDMARCA)
    BEGIN
        SET @MENSAJE = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Marca 
        SET NOMBRE = UPPER(@NOMBRE), DESCRIPCION = LOWER(@DESCRIPCION)
        WHERE IIDMARCA = @IIDMARCA

        SET @MENSAJE = 1        
    END
END
```

And in my controller at the moment I have the following:

```cs
public ActionResult ActualizarMarca(MarcaCLS oMarcaCLS)
{
    int a = 0;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (bd)
        {
            bd.SP_ACTUALIZAR_MARCA(iIDMARCA: oMarcaCLS.iidMarca, nOMBRE: oMarcaCLS.nombreMarca, dESCRIPCION: oMarcaCLS.descripcionMarca, mENSAJE:);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View(oMarcaCLS);
    }

    return View(oMarcaCLS);
}
```

[image]

The output message underlined in the image, I don't know how to catch it in my controller, I thought that with an integer variable I could but it generates the following

[image]

No argument has been given that corresponds to the required formal parameter.

I need the value of "@MENSAJE" of stored procedure in my controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ActualizarMarca(MarcaCLS oMarcaCLS)
        {
            ObjectParameter mensaje = new ObjectParameter("mensaje", typeof(int));//output
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (bd)
                    {
                        bd.SP_ACTUALIZAR_MARCA(iIDMARCA: oMarcaCLS.iidMarca, nOMBRE: oMarcaCLS.nombreMarca, dESCRIPCION: oMarcaCLS.descripcionMarca, mENSAJE: mensaje );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return View(oMarcaCLS);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(mensaje.Value);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to specify it as an OUT parameter?

Comment: yes, I have the variable, but it receives null, maybe it is to instantiate it badly, 
I just edited and added the parameter

Comment: bd.SP_ACTUALIZAR_MARCA(iIDMARCA: oMarcaCLS.iidMarca, nOMBRE: oMarcaCLS.nombreMarca, dESCRIPCION: oMarcaCLS.descripcionMarca, OUT mENSAJE: mensaje )